# Systemd tomcat.service failed with no errors

Tags: tomcat, centos, systemd

I have Tomcat configured to run as a service using Systemd on CentOS 7.2. I can start Tomcat with no problems:

```
sudo systemctl start tomcat
```

I can access the splash screen, the manager app, and even deploy applications. Then I shut down Tomcat:

```
sudo systemctl stop tomcat
```

I don't see any errors. But then I check the status:

```
sudo systemctl status tomcat

● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Sun 2016-10-30 17:27:19 UTC; 2s ago
  Process: 10833 ExecStop=/bin/kill -TERM $MAINPID (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 10785 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 10795 (code=exited, status=143)

Oct 30 17:26:31 java2016 systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
Oct 30 17:26:31 java2016 startup.sh[10785]: Existing PID file found during start.
Oct 30 17:26:31 java2016 startup.sh[10785]: Removing/clearing stale PID file.
Oct 30 17:26:31 java2016 systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Oct 30 17:27:19 java2016 systemd[1]: Stopping Apache Tomcat Web Application Container...
Oct 30 17:27:19 java2016 systemd[1]: tomcat.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=143/n/a
Oct 30 17:27:19 java2016 systemd[1]: Stopped Apache Tomcat Web Application Container.
Oct 30 17:27:19 java2016 systemd[1]: Unit tomcat.service entered failed state.
Oct 30 17:27:19 java2016 systemd[1]: tomcat.service failed.
```

It shows that `kill` functioned just fine. And `/opt/tomcat/logs/catalina.out` doesn't show any problems, either:

```
30-Oct-2016 17:27:19.268 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Oct-2016 17:27:19.324 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.pause Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
30-Oct-2016 17:27:19.375 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.stopInternal Stopping service Catalina
30-Oct-2016 17:27:19.491 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Oct-2016 17:27:19.493 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.stop Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
30-Oct-2016 17:27:19.494 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-nio-8080"]
30-Oct-2016 17:27:19.495 INFO [Thread-5] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.destroy Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
```

Why does Systemd consider Tomcat "failed"? Does it have anything to do with that "stale PID file" message?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Ah, never mind; this has been [answered already on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/a/695863) for general Java applications.

Basically Java programs sometimes don't send back the expected exit status when shutting down in response to SIGTERM. Adding the following to the `tomcat.service` file fixes the problem:

```
[Service]
SuccessExitStatus=143
```