# Ubuntu service stops randomly with "Main Process exited, status 143/n/a"

Tags: scala, ubuntu, crash, systemd, sigterm

My apps deployed as debians and started using systemd service.The app is getting crashed randomly. I am unable to find the reason for the crash.

I have 4 applications running[built using `java`, `scala`], out of which two are getting killed(named as `op` and `common`). All are started using systemd services.

Error on syslog is

> Jul 22 11:45:44 misqa mosquitto[2930]: Socket error on client
>   005056b76983-Common, disconnecting
>
> Jul 22 11:45:44 misqa systemd[1]: commonmod.service: Main process
>   exited, code=exited, status=143/n/a
>
> Jul 22 11:45:44 misqa systemd[1]: commonmod.service: Unit entered
>   failed state
>
> Jul 22 11:45:44 misqa systemd[1]: commonmod.service: Failed with
>   result 'exit-code'
>
> Jul 22 11:45:44 misqa systemd[1]: opmod.service: Main process exited,
>   code=exited, status=143/n/a
>
> Jul 22 11:45:44 misqa systemd[1]: opmod.service: Unit entered failed
>   state
>
> Jul 22 11:45:44 misqa systemd[1]: opmod.service: Failed with result
>   'exit-code'

But I am not getting any error on my application log file for both `op` and `common`

When I read more, I understood that the reason for crash is due to `SIGTERM` command, but unable to find out what is causing it. In any of these applications, I dont have exec commands for `killall`.

Is there anyway to identify which process is killing my applications.

My systemd service is like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=common Module
After=common-api
Requires=common-api

[Service]
TimeoutStartSec=0
ExecStart=/usr/bin/common-api

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically Java programs sometimes don't send back the expected exit status when shutting down in response to SIGTERM.

You should be able to suppress this by adding the exit code into the systemd service file as a "success" exit status:

```
[Service]
SuccessExitStatus=143
```

This solution was sucessful applied [here (serverfault)](https://serverfault.com/questions/695849/services-remain-in-failed-state-after-stopped-with-systemctl/695863#695863) and [here (stasckoverflow)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40331741/systemd-tomcat-service-failed-with-no-errors) both with java apps.